# Mysql join with time matching

Tags: mysql, join

I have two table cpuinfo and jobinfo. I want to create report using both data.

tabes;

```
CREATE TABLE `cpuinfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usagetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpuusage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)

CREATE TABLE `jobinfo` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `starttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `endtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobname` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
```

values:

```
cpuinfo
id,usagetime,cpuusage
1,"2011-03-12 11:10:01",40
2,"2011-03-12 11:10:31",45
3,"2011-03-12 11:11:01",45
4,"2011-03-12 11:11:31",43
5,"2011-03-12 11:12:01",55
6,"2011-03-12 11:12:31",49

jobinfo
id,starttime,endtime,jobname
1,"2011-03-12 11:10:01","2011-03-12 11:10:08","job a"
2,"2011-03-12 11:10:05","2011-03-12 11:10:18","job b"
3,"2011-03-12 11:10:15","2011-03-12 11:10:28","job c"
4,"2011-03-12 11:10:31","2011-03-12 11:10:38","job d"
5,"2011-03-12 11:10:45","2011-03-12 11:10:48","job e"
6,"2011-03-12 11:10:55","2011-03-12 11:10:55","job f"
7,"2011-03-12 11:11:31","2011-03-12 11:11:43","job d"
8,"2011-03-12 11:11:45","2011-03-12 11:11:49","job e"
9,"2011-03-12 11:11:55","2011-03-12 11:11:59","job f"
10,"2011-03-12 11:12:31","2011-03-12 11:12:43","job d"
11,"2011-03-12 11:12:45","2011-03-12 11:12:49","job e"
12,"2011-03-12 11:12:55","2011-03-12 11:12:59","job f"
```

I am looking output like this:

```
starttime,endtime,jobname,cpuusage
"2011-03-12 11:10:01","2011-03-12 11:10:08","job a",40
"2011-03-12 11:10:05","2011-03-12 11:10:18","job b",40
"2011-03-12 11:10:15","2011-03-12 11:10:28","job c",40
"2011-03-12 11:10:31","2011-03-12 11:10:38","job d",45
"2011-03-12 11:10:45","2011-03-12 11:10:48","job e",45
"2011-03-12 11:10:55","2011-03-12 11:10:55","job f",45
"2011-03-12 11:11:31","2011-03-12 11:11:43","job d",43
"2011-03-12 11:11:45","2011-03-12 11:11:49","job e",43
"2011-03-12 11:11:55","2011-03-12 11:11:59","job f",43
"2011-03-12 11:12:31","2011-03-12 11:12:43","job d",49
"2011-03-12 11:12:45","2011-03-12 11:12:49","job e",49
"2011-03-12 11:12:55","2011-03-12 11:12:59","job f",49
```

This SQL gives non-matching sql values to null

```
select a.starttime, a.endtime, a.jobname,b.cpuusage  from jobinfo a
    left join cpuinfo b on b.usagetime >= a.starttime and  b.usagetime <= a.endtime
```

Basically I want to list all the jobs and corresponding cpuusage during that job time.

Thanks
SR

Comment: What do you expect when you don't have any cpu usage in between that Job time?  And what if you have multiple cpuusage in that job duration?

Comment: we are importing from vmstat output, we will have the value. if time it not available, I can use the previous value. if I have multiple I can use last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT j.id, j.starttime, j.endtime, j.jobname, c.cpuusage
FROM
(
    SELECT j.id, j.starttime, j.endtime, j.jobname, MAX(c.usagetime) AS usagetime
    FROM jobinfo AS j
    LEFT JOIN cpuinfo AS c
    ON c.usagetime <= j.starttime
    GROUP BY j.id
) AS j
JOIN cpuinfo AS c
ON j.usagetime = c.usagetime
```

This gives the output you wanted. It finds the most recent value of cpuusage before the starttime of each job. It doesn't handle changes in cpuusage while the job is running.

Comment: it gave result what I want, but when load 4000 records on each table it tool 10 minutes to complate.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want NULL values in the result set, you can simply omit the rows that contain NULL values. And it can be done by using INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN:

```
select a.starttime, a.endtime, a.jobname,b.cpuusage  from jobinfo a
  inner join cpuinfo b on b.usagetime >= a.starttime and  b.usagetime <= a.endtime
```

If you do not want to omit any rows either, then you'll have to decide what to replace the NULLs with, and use `IFNULL` for that. For example, if you wanted to substitute all the NULLs with 0s, your script would be:

```
select a.starttime, a.endtime, a.jobname, ifnull(b.cpuusage, 0) as cpuusage
from jobinfo a
  left join cpuinfo b on b.usagetime >= a.starttime and  b.usagetime <= a.endtime
```

One more thing that was asked and not clarified by you is, how you'd like to see the results where there are more than one row in `cpuinfo` that match a row in `jobinfo`.

One way could be to simply output all the matches, and so if a job had several CPU events, it would be listed more than once accordingly.

If that is not appropriate, you could pick just one value, for example the most recent one, like [@Mark Byers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283849/mysql-join-with-time-matching/5283936#5283936) is proposing. But in that case some CPU events might end up being left out of the result set.

Here's a simple illustration:

```
         |CPU1                  |CPU2               |CPU3   
+--------+------+------+-------+------+-----------+-+------+-------
|Astart           |Aend   |Bstart          |Cstart         |Bend   |Cend
```

During the `B` job there were two events, CPU<sub>2</sub> and CPU<sub>3</sub>. The latter was also the only event that happened during the `C` job. If we picked only the most recent events for every job, then CPU<sub>2</sub> wouldn't make it to the results, because it only happened during one job and wasn't the most recent one for it.

A solution that would include all the events without duplicating the jobs, might be to output all the events in one column as a list of values. That could be solved with the help of `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
select
  a.starttime, a.endtime, a.jobname,
  group_concat(convert(ifnull(b.cpuusage, 0), char) separator ',') as cpuusage
from jobinfo a
  left join cpuinfo b on b.usagetime >= a.starttime and  b.usagetime <= a.endtime
```

As you can see, we are also using `CONVERT` here, because now we need to convert numbers to strings before concatenating them.